# Scenario in which Dominated Convergence does not hold

Tags: probability-theory

For $X,X_n,Y \in \mathscr L^1, n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\lvert X_n \rvert \le Y, Y \ge 0$. By the dominated convergence theorem:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} E[X_n] = E[X]
$$
and can be proven by Fatou's Lemma. I am trying to find an example of a a probability space and random variables $X,X_n \in \mathscr L^1$ where $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = X$ but not $
\lim_{n \to \infty} E[X_n] = E[X]
$

I thought that this would be impossible given the dominated convergence theorem ?

Comment: In which sense do you want $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = X$? Almost everywhere? In this case, consider the unit interval with Lebesgue measure and $X_n=n\mathbf 1(0,1/n)$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo What would X be in this case?

Comment: In this case $X=0$.

Comment: So $E[X] = 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} E[X_n] = \lim_{n \to \infty} n P(X_n \in ( 0,\frac{1}{n})$ ?

Comment: The expectation of $X_n$ has a problem: it should be equal to $1$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo The expectation of the indicator is just the probability of the event right? So, in this case it is the probability that $X_n$ is in the interval $(0,0)$. Could you tell me where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the unit interval with Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ and $X_n=n\cdot\mathbf 1(0,1/n)$. Then $X_n\to X:=0$ almost everywhere and for each $n$, 
$$\mathbb E[X_n]=n\cdot\mathbb E\left[\mathbf 1\left(0,\frac 1n\right)\right]=n\cdot\lambda\left(0,\frac 1n\right)=n\cdot \frac 1n =1.$$